# Itens do dropdown menu do Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e coloquei o menu do bootstrap na minha aplicação mas ao clicar no icon `<b class="caret"></b>` os itens do dropdown-menu não aparecem.

Menu ao clicar no icon `<b class="caret"></b>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tag `<head></head>`

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

     <!-- BOOTSTRAP --> 

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <!-- OUTRAS BIBLIOTECAS --> 
     <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

     <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css"> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script></head>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="body-wrap" >

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="azul">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <div class="conteudo"><li><a href="#">PAGINA PRINCIPAL</a></li></div> 
                    <div class="conteudo"> <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li></div>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRODUTOS <b class="caret"></b></a></div>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bermudas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, o próprio bootstrap faz o dropdown.
Testa com esse código:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tela</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Principal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Produtos <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ações</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ações</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```